# Scala Build failing?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala when Iam trying to execute sbt update I am getting

```
[error] /home/workspace/Scala/SparkTwitterStreaming/project/project/build.scala:1: expected class or object definition
[error] name := "SparkTwitterStreaming"
[error] ^
[error] /home/workspace/Scala/SparkTwitterStreaming/project/project/build.scala:2: expected class or object definition
[error] version := "1.0"
[error] ^
[error] /home/workspace/Scala/SparkTwitterStreaming/project/project/build.scala:3: expected class or object definition
[error] scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
[error] ^
[error] /home/workspace/Scala/SparkTwitterStreaming/project/project/build.scala:5: expected class or object definition
[error] libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2"
[error] ^
[error] /home/workspace/Scala/SparkTwitterStreaming/project/project/build.scala:6: expected class or object definition
[error] libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
[error] ^
[error] 5 errors found
```

`build.scala` / `build.sbt` ??

```
name := "SparkTwitterStreaming"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
```

Comment: What does your `build.scala`/`build.sbt` look like ? And in which directory are you running your `sbt update` commans ?

Comment: `name := "SparkTwitterStreaming"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2".
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"` Folder SourceFolder: SparkTwitterStreaming> which has bin,src,project

Comment: What is it? Is it `build.sbt`? or `build.scala` ? What directory is it located in ? What is direcory structure of your sbt project ? Where are you invoking sbt from? Please include all that in your question.

Comment: Also... what is this `.` doing at the end of `"spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2". `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing `.scala` and `.sbt` files. SBT allows defining build in two different ways. `.scala` files are, well, normal Scala files, so they can't have code (and `name := "SparkTwitterStreaming"` etc. in SBT are just Scala code) on top level, it has to be inside a trait/class/object. SBT itself takes care of wrapping `.sbt` files in this way.

`SparkTwitterStreaming/project/project/build.scala` also looks wrong: there *are* cases in SBT when you'd use a file under `project/project`, but this isn't one of them. You probably want to move this file to `SparkTwitterStreaming/build.sbt`.

Answer (score 2):

So basically... a valid minimal sbt project has a structure like following,

```
YourProject
├── build.sbt
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── Main.scala
```

And a bit more detailed project will be like this,

```
SparkTwitterStreaming
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   └── plugins.sbt
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── YouCode.scala
```

And a minimal `build.sbt` looks like,

```
name := "SparkTwitterStreaming"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
```

Now some people like to use `build.scala` instead of `build.sbt`, in that case this `build.scala` should be located inside `SparkTwitterStreaming/project` directory.

```
SparkTwitterStreaming
├── project
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── plugins.sbt
│   └── build.scala
└── src
    └── main
        └── scala
            └── YouCode.scala
```

Also, for above `build.sbt`, the equivalent `build.scala` will look like,

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {   // <--- here MyBuild can be renamed to anything
  // if you needed extra resolvers
  val pResolvers = Seq(
    "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
  )

  val pDependencies = Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2",
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
  )

  val pBuildSettings = Seq (
    name := "SparkTwitterStreaming",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
    resolvers ++= pResolvers,
    libraryDependencies ++= pDependencies
  )

  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(pBuildSettings)
}
```